# SocketChannel write( ) returns with no error but no data was actually sent

Tags: java, sockets, nio, socketchannel

I am using SocketChannel to communicate with remote server. I send data using socketChannel.write() with no errors and exceptions, however, the server log indicates no data was received; client tcp traffic monitor also shows that the string message in the ByteBuffer was not sent.

Could anyone give me a hint why this is the case? Thank you!

```
public class Client implements Runnable {
    SocketChannel socketChannel;
    Selector selector;
    SelectionKey key;
    ByteBuffer inbuf, outbuf;
    int id;
    @Override
    public void run() {
    try {
        // prepare inbuf and outbuf
        inbuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(10000);
        outbuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(10000);

        // prepare a socket channel for communication
        socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
        socketChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("<remote server ip>", ));
        selector = Selector.open();
        socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        key = socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ
                | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);

        while (selector.select() > 0) {

            if (key.isReadable()) {
                // read from channel when server sends data
                read();
            }

            if (key.isWritable()) {
                // write
                Random r = new Random(500);
                write("b", r.nextInt(), r.nextInt());
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    // write a message to server after 1 second
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    write("m", r.nextInt(), r.nextInt());
                }
                write("e", r.nextInt(), r.nextInt());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void write(String action, int x, int y) throws IOException {
    String msg = String.format("%s:%d:%d:%d", action, id, x, y);
    int r=outbuf.remaining();

    outbuf.put(msg.getBytes());
    int rBytes = outbuf.remaining();
    boolean connected = socketChannel.isConnected();
    Socket sock = socketChannel.socket();

    if (connected && sock.isConnected() && !sock.isOutputShutdown())
>>>>>>>>>>    socketChannel.write(outbuf);
    else
        System.out.println("Connection broken!");

    System.out.printf("Client %d told server:%s\n", id, msg);
    //outbuf.clear();
}

   ... //read omitted here
```

Comment: Did you flip() the ByteBuffer? Edit: no, you didnt...I'm writing the answer.

Comment: Thank you! Hi@EJP, could you please take a look of another question asked by me? Thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965436/socketchannel-selector-vs-plain-socket?lq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After putting stuff into a Buffer, or reading stuff into it you have to flip the buffer to write or get the data from it. Check the `flip()` method in the Buffer class. The docs say

> Flips this buffer. The limit is set to the current position and then the position is set to zero. If the mark is defined then it is discarded.
>   After a sequence of channel-read or put operations, invoke this method to prepare for a sequence of channel-write or relative get operations.

So adding a buffer.flip() after the put should do the trick :)

Comment: +1 and don't ignore the value returned by `write().` It would have been zero in this case, which should have triggered alarm bells.

Comment: Thank you @xp500, it works! I indeed read that ByteBuffer or Buffer class in general can be 'flipped' between read and write mode. Since this works, does that mean after I 'put' some bytes in the ByteBuffer, the SocketChannel write() method will actually READ the buffer and write it through the outputStream of the socket? Thanks

Comment: @user798637 check the docs for the buffer class. It defines 3 properties: limit, position and capacity. I assume that the write method somehow iterates through the buffer (probably using the hasRemaining() method) and then writes it to the stream. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: @xp500, yes, thank you. If you don't mind I ask here another related question without starting a new thread, here it is: now after 'flipping' the buffer, the traffic monitor indicates my data was sent, but the server does seem to get it, because my server has very simple logic, whenever it get something, it simply echoes it to all the other connected clients (broadcast), I tested my server with nc command and it works. So I am wondering what's still wrong here.

Comment: Same or other problem in your server. You'll have to post the code of course.